# CMAKE cannot recognize Cudnn whilte it's installed

Tags: opencv, cmake, cudnn

I installed CUDA 10.2, and installed matching CUDNN, but CMAKE cannot recognize it while I try to install OpenCV with CUDA.
I already copied Cudnn files from bin, include, and lib folders to the corresponding CUDA folders. I tried several versions of Cudnn, but I still get the same error.

Here is CMAKE's configuring output:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
Detected processor: AMD64
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.0.2, BUILD = opencv-4.1.1-libjpeg-turbo
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
at: C:/opencv-4.1.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
at: C:/opencv-4.1.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
Could NOT find CUDNN: Found unsuitable version "..", but required is at least "6" (found C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64/cudnn.lib)
CUDA detected: 10.2
CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-D_FORCE_INLINES
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Found VTK 8.2.0 (C:/Program Files/PCL 1.10.0/3rdParty/VTK/lib/cmake/vtk-8.2/UseVTK.cmake)
OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: C:/opencv-4.1.1/build/python_loader
Caffe:   NO
Protobuf:   NO
Glog:   NO
freetype2:   NO
harfbuzz:    NO
Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags
Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': C:/opencv-4.1.1/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
Tesseract:   NO
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):
  CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
  directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1059 (include)



General configuration for OpenCV 4.1.1 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            C:/opencv_contrib-4.1.1/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-12-02T22:50:32Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.19041 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.18.0
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 16 2019
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1928

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (13 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (27 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (2 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.28.29333.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP8   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP8   /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise       /MP8    /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise       /MP8  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO 
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          cudart_static.lib C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64/cuda.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppicom.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab viz xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv freetype hdf java js matlab ovis python2 sfm
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 YES (ver 8.2.0)

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.2-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.35.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.20.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.22.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.3.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
           at:                   C:/opencv-4.1.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
              at:                C:/opencv-4.1.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.2, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             61
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         NO

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/opencv-4.1.1/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Users/hedey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe (ver 3.6.2)
    Libraries:                   C:/Users/hedey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/libs/python36.lib (ver 3.6.2)
    numpy:                       C:/Users/hedey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.14.1)
    install path:                C:/Users/hedey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/cv2/python-3.6

  Python (for build):            C:/Users/hedey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/opencv-4.1.1/build/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** for show the **text**. Please, [edit] the question post and copy-paste CMake output into it as **text**. You may format pasted text as code, with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button. See also [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I edited the question as requested, and I look forward to receiving and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for a similar problem in the following link:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cudnn-found-but-version-cant-be-deduced/145551/12?u=hedeya1980

So, I changed the following line in 'opencv-4.1.1\cmake':

`file(READ "${CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR}/cudnn.h" CUDNN_H_CONTENTS)`
to be as follows:

```
file(READ "${CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR}/cudnn_version.h" CUDNN_H_CONTENTS)
```